# including Angstrom and Greek letters in gnuplot?

Tags: encoding, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot and would like to get the symbol for "Angstrom" (iso encoding 305) and the Greek letter Delta (Symbol 104) in the plot. How can I combine the two encoding schemes when producing my output eps?

Answer (score 1):

This works without problem for me using UTF8 character for Angstrom and either the `Symbol` font or the UTF8 character for Δ :

```
set xlabel "{/Symbol D} Δ (Å)"
```

Gives in PDF terminal : 
[image: result]

with encoding to default but UTF8 as system wide locale:

```
gnuplot> show encoding

nominal character encoding is default
however LC_CTYPE in current locale is fr_FR.UTF-8
```

Comment: `{/Symbol \104}{\305}`... hmm maybe [some words more](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536930/66388). `:-)`